# wpf fixeddocument dynamic data

Tags: c#, wpf, fixeddocument

I am creating `FixedDocument` and adding pages to it dynamically.

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    FixedDocument fd = new FixedDocument();
    TextBlock page1Text = new TextBlock();

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();


        fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth, pd.PrintableAreaHeight);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
            page1.Width = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
            page1.Height = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

            pages();
            page1.Children.Add(page1Text);
            PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
            ((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1);
            fd.Pages.Add(page1Content);
        }

        DocumentViewer dr = new DocumentViewer();
        dr.Height = 700;
        dr.Document =fd;

        stack.Children.Add(dr);


    }

    private void pages()
    {
        page1Text.Text = "This is a test";
        page1Text.FontSize = 40;
        page1Text.Margin = new Thickness(96);

    }

}
```

The code is still giving error that page1content is a child of another parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it. The solution is as follows

```
private void Print_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();


fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth,fd.PrintableAreaHeight);

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
            page1.Width = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
            page1.Height = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

            UIElement page1Text = pages();
            page1.Children.Add(page1Text);
            PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
            ((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1);
            fd.Pages.Add(page1Content);
        }

        DocumentViewer dr = new DocumentViewer();
        dr.Height = 700;
        dr.Document =fd;

        stack.Children.Add(dr);


    }

    private UIElement pages()
    {
        Canvas pcan = new Canvas();

        TextBlock page1Text = new TextBlock();
        page1Text.Text = "This is a test";
        page1Text.FontSize = 40;
        page1Text.Margin = new Thickness(96);

        pcan.Children.Add(page1Text);


        return pcan;
    }
```

You can skip the canvas. It is requirment of my project so I was trying it.

Answer (score 3):

It is an easy error to diagnose; an visual can only **ever** have one parent as otherwise you would have a circular dependency in the `VisualTree`. Review your code to check if you are using the same visual twice.

If you want the visual to appear in two places simultaneously then you need to duplicate it; if the second use is intentional then you can un-parent visual by removing itself from the parent. e.g. (`canvas.Parent.Remove(canvas)`).

In the code sample posted I can identify at **least one** instance of where this would occur and have detailed this below.

---

You are adding the instance of `vCanvas` to more than once in your `while(loop)` block. You need to create a new `Canvas` for each iteration.

```
var visual = /* unknown */;
var fd = new FixedDocument();   
while(loop)
{
    var canvas = PageInit();
    var page = new FixedPage();
    page.Width = visual.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
    page.Height = visual.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
    page.Children.Add(canvas);

    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(page);
    visual.Pages.Add(pageContent);
}
```

For the purposes of this example, I will the `Canvas` in the `PageInit()`.

```
private Canvas PageInit()
{
    var tb = new TextBlock();
    tb.Text = "From Data";
    var canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.Children.Add(tb);

    return canvas;
}
```

Comment: It is giving the same error now for 'canvas' that this element is already a part of another parent. i used Canvas canvas = new Canvas(); canvas = printinit(); is it the correct syntax.

Comment: As you have not posted a **complete** code example I cannot help you further (nor do I want to). I have edited my answer to explain the problem a bit more clearly. Good luck.