# How to use WriteAsync with XPSDocument?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, printing, xps

I have an issue with that code,

```
XpsDocument doc = new XpsDocument(_filePath, FileAccess.Read);
XpsDocument = doc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
...
var writer = PrintQueue.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(pq);
var paginator = XpsDocument.DocumentPaginator;
writer.WritingCancelled += WriterOnWritingCancelled;
writer.WritingCompleted += WriterOnWritingCompleted;
writer.WritingPrintTicketRequired += WriterOnWritingPrintTicketRequired;
writer.WriteAsync(paginator);
```

If I replace the last Ligne with Write(paginator) everything is ok, but if I use the write async I get a,

> FixedPage cannot contain another FixedPage.

error in `WriterOnWritingCompleted`;

I found that [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/841e804b-9130-4476-8709-0d2854c11582/exception-fixedpage-cannot-contain-another-fixedpage-when-printing-to-the-xps-document-writer?forum=wpf). But I don't really know how to deal with that overload.

Comment: Try to await writer.WriteAsync(paginator); using async and await keyword

Comment: Thanks Vimal, but writer.WriteAsync(paginator) returns void, so not awaitable

Comment: Why do you need the `WriteAsync()` method? I mean, you could stay with `Write()` (if it does its job). If you want some asynchronous processing, you could wrap your call in an awaitable `Task`: `await Task.Run(() => writer.Write()).ContinueWith(t => this.WriterOnWritingCompleted());`. You can also add the `CancellationToken` for cancellation possibility.

Comment: I tried, but Write() needs to be run on the UI thread...

Answer (score 2):

You could try this [code](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEcQFjAF&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2Fa%2Ff%2F7%2Faf7777e5-7dcd-4800-8a0a-b18336565f5b%2Fxps-read.doc&ei=DSebVOqUN4SHygOuwoKADA&usg=AFQjCNETGP7SeODP2pE5S-wLQ3coZgvbLw&sig2=13YmajkVCYMODBo7kfp4vA&bvm=bv.82001339,d.bGQ):

```
private void WriteUsingAsync (
            string XPSDocFileName, object FixedDocFromApplication) 
    {
        // create a new XPS Document for output
        //  note that AsyncXpsDoc is a property defined in the
        //   class containing this method.
        AsyncXpsDoc = new XpsDocument(XPSDocFileName,
            FileAccess.ReadWrite);

    // create a doc writer object based on the open XPS Document
    XpsDocumentWriter XpsDocWrtr =
        XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(AsyncXpsDoc);

    // register the writing completed event handler
    XpsDocWrtr.WritingCompleted +=
        new WritingCompletedEventHandler(AsyncPrintCompleted);
    XpsDocWrtr.WriteAsync((FixedDocument)FixedDocFromApplication);

    return;
}

// Completion Event Handler
private void AsyncPrintCompleted(
    object sender, WritingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.Cancelled) || (e.Error != null))
        //document not written
    else
        // Asynchronous operation Completed

    AsyncXpsDoc.Close();
    AsyncXpsDoc = null;
}
```

And check that you create fixedDocument in the right way, [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116850/wpf-fixeddocument-dynamic-data):

```
var fd = new FixedDocument(); 
fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth,fd.PrintableAreaHeight);
FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
page1.Width = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
page1.Height = fd.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;
UIElement page1Text = pages();
page1.Children.Add(page1Text);
PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1);
fd.Pages.Add(page1Content);

private UIElement pages()
    {
        Canvas pcan = new Canvas();

        TextBlock page1Text = new TextBlock();
        page1Text.Text = "This is a test";
        page1Text.FontSize = 40;
        page1Text.Margin = new Thickness(96);

        pcan.Children.Add(page1Text);


        return pcan;
    }
```